# ERROR in @angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-template

I have downloaded some angular template which makes use of angular material library... I was trying the run this template on my local machine.. I have  successfully executed the `npm install`.. but while `ng serve`.. I am getting the warnings & errors like below,

```
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.7) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

@angular/compiler-cli@4.4.7 requires typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0' but 2.5.3 was found instead.
Using this version can result in undefined behaviour and difficult to debug problems.

Please run the following command to install a compatible version of TypeScript.

    npm install typescript@'>=2.1.0 <2.4.0'

To disable this warning run "ng set warnings.typescriptMismatch=false".

** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 11% building modules 13/15 modules 2 active ...modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.jswebpack: wait until bundle finished: /
Date: 2018-07-01T07:48:54.668Z
Hash: 7980dfc21e378497af3e
Time: 30697ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 1.91 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 595 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 211 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 20.4 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/sidenav.es5.js
1007:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js
101:59-75 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/slider.es5.js
1073:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1132:164-170 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1132:62-78 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js
122:149-155 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js
122:167-173 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js
122:57-73 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
1334:59-75 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/progress-bar.es5.js
143:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js
164:149-155 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js
164:57-73 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/button.es5.js
168:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1700:152-158 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1700:182-188 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1700:198-204 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1700:58-74 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1903:143-149 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1903:184-190 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
1903:55-71 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
2108:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
2186:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/button.es5.js
222:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
2427:140-146 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
2427:156-162 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
2427:54-70 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js
258:158-164 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js
258:180-186 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js
258:60-76 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
266:152-158 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
266:168-174 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
266:58-74 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/progress-spinner.es5.js
293:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
3345:170-176 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
3345:193-199 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
3345:211-217 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
3345:64-80 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/progress-spinner.es5.js
341:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
362:143-149 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js
362:55-71 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/sort.es5.js
384:59-75 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js
38:65-81 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js
39:11-17 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/collections.es5.js
462:67-83 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/slide-toggle.es5.js
499:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
517:143-149 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
517:161-167 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/scrolling.es5.js
517:55-71 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js
525:11-17 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/checkbox.es5.js
570:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
604:167-173 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
604:193-199 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
604:216-222 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
604:232-238 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
604:63-79 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/stepper.es5.js
65:56-72 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js
677:146-152 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js
677:163-169 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js
677:170-178 "export 'INJECTOR' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js
677:181-187 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/bottom-sheet.es5.js
677:56-72 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
719:179-185 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
719:67-83 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/paginator.es5.js
72:58-74 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js
788:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js
79:128-134 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js
79:50-66 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
816:149-155 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
816:172-178 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
816:194-200 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js
816:57-73 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
821:152-158 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js
821:58-74 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/radio.es5.js
821:83-104 "export 'ANIMATION_MODULE_TYPE' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js
86:140-146 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js
86:146-152 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js
86:54-70 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/bidi.es5.js
86:56-72 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:137-143 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:154-160 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:177-183 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:184-192 "export 'INJECTOR' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:195-201 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:223-229 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:248-254 "export 'inject' was not found in '@angular/core'

WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/snack-bar.es5.js
911:53-69 "export 'defineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'

ERROR in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts (15,17): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-origin.d.ts (18,21): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (136,21): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts (154,104): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (56,15): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in 
/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/slide-toggle/typings/slide-toggle.d.ts (58,18): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext 
(/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/home/rahul/Downloads/FriendColony_Web/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:493:24)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "2.4.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.6",
    "angular2-image-upload": "^1.0.0-rc.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-ui-auth": "^7.0.2",
    "ng2-uploader": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.1",
    "secure-ls": "^1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.6.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.0.47",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.8.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  },
  "description": "This project was generated with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) version 1.4.1.",
  "main": "karma.conf.js",
  "author": ""
}
```

My System Configuration

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.7
Node: 8.11.2
OS: linux x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.7
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.7
@schematics/angular          0.6.7
@schematics/update           0.6.7
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

Comment: what are the dependencies of the "template" that you are trying to use?

Comment: and why are you using the build versions for cdk and material? you cant use the latest build of cdk/material (angular v6) and angular v4.

Answer (score 1):

in your package.json try :

```
"@angular/core": "^4.4.6",
```

replace:

```
"@angular/cdk": "^4.4.6",
"@angular/material": "^4.4.6",
```

`npm i` again.

Comment: npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cdk@^4.4.6

Comment: did you cleared your node module and package.lock ? and npm i again?

Comment: OK, try ```"@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",```